# Raising $n^i$ and its implications

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I was watching a video about the Riemann zeta function for fun (I wanted to figure out what the non-trivial zero meme was all about) and at about $\boxed{4:50}$ in the video, there was an explanation of numbers raised to $i$.

The video link is [here.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sD0NjbwqlYwhttp://)

Needless to say, I have some conundrums with this concept.

- I realize that multiplying numbers by $i$ in the Argand diagram have rotational properties, but why does *raising* them to $i$ have this more continuous, less discrete rotation?
- Why does raising $n$ to $i$ where $n$ is farther and farther away from $1$ cause the output path to have, for lack of a better word, greater angular acceleration?

Comment: Yet another person who pretends to explain maths while obscuring them. For starters, there is no canonical definition of $x^i$ when $x$ is real positive. Of course, one could try to define $$x^i=e^{i\log x}$$ for the usual natural logarithm defined on $(0,+\infty)$, since $$x=e^{\log x}$$ but the trouble is that $x$ is also $$x=e^{\log x+2ki\pi}$$ "hence" one would also "deduce" that $$x^i=e^{(\log x+2ki\pi)i}=e^{i\log x}e^{-2k\pi}$$ for every integer $k$, that is, not one, not two, but a countable number of different values...

Answer (score 1):

Think about how $n^s$ is defined.  For $s=\sigma + it$, $n^s = n^{\sigma}n^{it}$.  Using the principal branch of the logarithm we find $n^{it}=e^{it \log n}$ which for any fixed $t$ is just a "phase" $\cos(t\log n) + i\sin(t\log n)$.  Multiplication by a phase is a rotation in the complex plane, so multiplication by $n^i$ is a rotation by an angle of $\log n$